# Number of weeks between dates

Tags: apex, date

I have two `Date` values. I need to find number of weeks between them. I want to do it `Apex Class`. Not looking for formula fields.

So far I tried:

```
Integer numberofweeks = (projectStartDate - opp.Project_Start_Date__c)/7;
```

I receive this error:

> Date arithmetic expressions must use Integer or Long arguments

Comment: When you have information to add, please [edit] your post to include it instead of burying it in comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the `Date.daysBetween` method to get the difference between two `Date` values. The following works for me:

```
Date today = Date.today();
Date nextWeek = Date.today().addDays(7);
system.assertEquals(1, today.daysBetween(nextWeek)/7);
```

Comment: thanks. it worked. my stupid mind didn't think this logic.

Comment: @Razu Not stupid, but just remember the documentation is really helpful sometimes!

Answer (score 1):

Here it is an example:

ApexTest:

```
@isTest
private class DateExampleTest {

    @isTest static void test_method_one() {
        //test 7 days diff
        Date startDate = Date.today().addDays(0);
        Date endDate = Date.today().addDays(7);

        Integer diffDays = startDate.daysBetween(endDate);

        System.debug(diffDays);
        System.assertEquals(7, diffDays);

        Integer diffWeeks = diffDays / 7;

        System.debug(diffWeeks);
        System.assertEquals(1, diffWeeks);

        //test 15 days diff
        startDate = Date.today().addDays(0);
        endDate = Date.today().addDays(15);

        diffDays = startDate.daysBetween(endDate);

        System.debug(diffDays);
        System.assertEquals(15, diffDays);

        diffWeeks = diffDays / 7;

        System.debug(diffWeeks);
        System.assertEquals(2, diffWeeks);

        //test 14 days diff back and forward
        startDate = Date.today().addDays(-7);
        endDate = Date.today().addDays(7);

        diffDays = startDate.daysBetween(endDate);

        System.debug(diffDays);
        System.assertEquals(14, diffDays);

        diffWeeks = diffDays / 7;

        System.debug(diffWeeks);
        System.assertEquals(2, diffWeeks);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

My initial approach would be to create a new formula field called "`Number of Weeks` " which would have the value of `(date2-date1)/7`

In the apex class you'd have something like

```
Integer x = date1.daysBetween(date2) /7;
```

Comment: I want to do it in Apex class

Comment: post first your current apex code and I'll help you modify it

Comment: Integer numberofweeks = (projectStartDate - opp.Project_Start_Date__c)/7; it is giving error.

Comment: can you psot the error as well?

Comment: error : Date arithmetic expressions must use Integer or Long arguments

Comment: u can use the Ineger i =date1.daysbetween(date2)